# Unable to install drivers for TP Link AC 1300 archer t4u wireless dual band usb adapter on ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, drivers, wireless, tp-link

I have seen plenty of guides and questions but none is helping. the official website of tp-link provide drivers for kernel not later than 3.8 but i am using kernel version 4.10 and ubuntu 16.04. How can i install this. Or is it capable to run on latest version of ubuntu? Output of `lsusb` is

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04f2:b34f Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 2357:010d  
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 09da:054f A4Tech Co., Ltd. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

where my device is
    `Bus 001 Device 004: ID 2357:010d`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: i have seen this. this is for ac1200

Comment: Hold on, I'll look into the code.

Comment: This driver supports the AC1300 as well.

Comment: please wait while i try

Comment: alright. i am done with the process. The device started to blink with intervals of 15 seconds or so. Now what??

Comment: Connect to some wireless network and use it.

Comment: i am not seeing any option for tp link adapter to let it scan

Comment: Did you reboot? Or restart NM?

Comment: nope. rebooting now

Comment: One last question. what should i learn to read these codes and understand them. I mean how did u come to know that it will work for ac1300

Comment: I looked into the driver source code. There is nothing in these commands.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64834/discussion-between-root-and-pilot6).